# extensions::webstore:34 Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be started by the top frame

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I caught this exception on my ASP.NET project. I don't handle any jquery or javascript error. What is the reason this exception?

I searched all similar problems but all of them are using google extension. But I don't use any extension on my project.

After I caught this exception on my project, opened another project on google chrome I seem similar exception. Maybe problem why reason is google chrome.

***Error***: extensions::webstore:34 Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be started by the top frame.

Comment: Do you have third party ads on your page?

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by some embedded iframe calling [`chrome.webstore` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore) that handles [inline installs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation).

The error basically says "you can't use inline installs from iframes".

Check all embedded frames.

It's also possible that your Chrome has some fishy extension installed that tried to inject frames into your pages. Check if the error reproduces in Incognito.

Comment: thanks a lot for answer. but i am confused. i checked frame with ctrl+f . i can't understand if there is a problem or  how to search iframe problems? also, run project in Incognito but i get exception "Uncaught Chrome Web Store installations can only be started by the top frame.". Thank you for taking the time ,again.

Comment: Check for `chrome.webstore` in JavaScript sources in DevTools

Comment: when i saw this exception, firstly i research chrome.webstore.  but i cant find key chrome.webstore. i am so sorry for taking your time.i cant resolve